# How can I generate Excel spreadsheets on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I got the requirement to output some reports as Excel 2002 spreadsheets.

Normally a job for reporting services - however - that's "not great IMO" and I hate it so for this project I used ExtJs - which doesn't do any excel output - not really - but does do the UI really, really well.

The reports will need to have outlining, grouping summaries and all sorts of formatting not available if I use the plain XML formatting.  This is the one thing Reporting services does do really well. Gutted.

So... Does anyone have any suggestions for alternatives to reporting services and definitely not installing Office on the server? Crystal reports are just as "not great IMO" as RS so not that either :)

I have looked at aspose et al but they're a bit expensive and I'd like to find something open-source, if possible - such as perhaps using open office -, if I can find a way of using OOo on the server without actually installing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited to soften wording slightly - I'm not against profanity when necessary, but it didn't really add anything here...

Comment: i think it did - bit of a nanny state of affairs?

Comment: "nanny state": not really; merely that it doesn't (from what I've seen) necessarily put people in the constructive/helpful mindset if you're simply product-bashing. If you really want, feel free to edit/rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the OpenXml SDK route - which is a bit of a PITA in some situs but good in others - once you get the hang of it...

Answer (score 1):

If your reports are not very large perhaps you can get away using the [free version of Gembox Spreadsheed](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheetFree.htm)?

Comment: It's a shame because we def go over 150 lines - but only for probably 30% of the reports gened :(

Comment: Still, while their commercial license is not for free, it's not a robbery either, and the product is good (we are using it extensively in a project since a year or so). If you have the money for it (~$500) it's worth giving it a shot.

Comment: i'm just reading up on the licensing :)

Cheers

if anyone has any experience with Open Office i'd still like to hear from you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Perl module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel works very well at generating reports in Excel format.

Comment: i don't know perl - my gut feeling is that that is to my determent.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it and requires only ASP.NET 2.0 on the server (no reliance on Excel or any other libraries).

You can see live ASP.NET (VB and C#) Excel Reporting samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx).

If performance is important at all, I would suggest running your own performance tests with your actual data and formatting as you compare your options.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Hey Joe...

I decided to go with the ooxml route and use converters on the older machines. gives us a bnit more flex - your product would have been the choice otherwise.

w://

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on budget, time and whether r not you're allowed to install coms on the server -

for us all of the above were negative,

we needed the follwing:

export of generic data
grouping of certain columns
sumarisation of certain columns
template based output

sql server reporting services offered all of this if - and only if you adhered to their rules.

what we have now is near as damn it ad-hoc reporting - using extjs for the ui, nhib for the domain castle windsor for the binding, and ooxml sdk 2.0 for the export.

if you need the code for the ulti level grouping excel output give me a shout :)

w://

Answer (score 0):

I am working on (right now) a windows service that does Excel and PDF generation and merging on the server, unattended, using the SyncFusion [XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/back-office/xlsio) components.

So far this has been effective.  The only limitation I have run into is the ability to read some 'legacy' html/xml based Excel formats.

Not Open Source, or free unfortunately but it is a workable option.